# Is there a way to rollback the specific save points in a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Let's say I have SQL transaction with three save points as below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
--Insert Value 1
SAVE TRANSACTION FirstInsert -- 1st Save Point
--Insert Value 2
SAVE TRANSACTION SecondInsert -- 2nd Save Point
--Insert Value 3 
SAVE TRANSACTION ThirdInsert -- 3rd Save Point
--Insert Value 4
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SecondInsert 
COMMIT
```

If I rollback "SecondInsert" save point, the 4th insert value also got rollback. Is there a way to rollback only the SecondInsert save point? so that 4th inserted value will remain in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   Value INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE TestTable; 
DECLARE @vSecondInsert NCHAR(50)='SecondInsert' 
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
   INSERT INTO TestTable( ID, Value )   VALUES  ( 1, N'10')
   -- this will create a savepoint after the first INSERT
   SAVE TRANSACTION FirstInsert 
   INSERT INTO TestTable( ID, Value )   VALUES  ( 2, N'20')
   -- this will create a savepoint after the second INSERT
   SAVE TRANSACTION @vSecondInsert
   INSERT INTO TestTable( ID, Value )   VALUES  ( 3, N'30') 
   SAVE TRANSACTION ThirdInsert
   INSERT INTO TestTable( ID, Value )   VALUES  ( 4, N'40')
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @vSecondInsert 
COMMIT 
SELECT * FROM TestTable
```

Comment: No, this is incoherent. Save points are sequential points in time, just like transactions as a whole are. Rolling back to the second save point necessarily undoes everything that happened after it; that's the only way to ensure consistency. If you want inserts to happen independently, don't put them in the same transaction (or be prepared to re-issue them).

Comment: No transaction goes by chain

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.